# Nginx - lua error

Tags: nginx, lua

```
unknown directive access_by_lua_file
```

Пытаюсь связать нгинкс с луа файлом:

```
Feb 02 01:14:12 vm4210117 nginx[30956]: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "access_by_lua_file" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:29
```

По итогу ничего не получается, как решить?

Debian 10

Answer (score 1):

Прежде чем использовать Lua директивы нужно установить [Lua модуль](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/)

Answer (score 0):

Можете установить Lua модуль, либо использовать готовую сборку под названием [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/en/)

Если используете докер, то образ [openresty/openresty](https://hub.docker.com/r/openresty/openresty):

```
FROM openresty/openresty
...
```